# how to add toggle function to sub children of <li> in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when i am trying to add toggle function to the child nodes nothing is happening could you help me out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('label.tree-toggler').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(300);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li><label class="tree-toggler nav-header">WorkLoad</label>
    <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
      <li><label class="tree1">DME Report</label>
        <ul class="tree1">
          <li>
            <a href="search.php">Report1</a>
            <a href="search.php">Report2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="update.php">CAMB Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="index2.php">LMAB Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DMF Notification</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LME Forecast Report</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean nothing is happening>?

Comment: Works fine for me. Even the code snippet runs correctly

Comment: Using .closest() instead of parent and .find() instead of children would help to clear the logic. What exactly do you try to achieve?

Comment: @adosi the OP is referring to grandchild level `li` elements

Comment: i mean toggle working fine for the parent node but not for children nodes i need child nodes to be toggled as parent do

Answer (score 0):

This would allow to simplify the above code to:

> The code below mostly works as intended, ...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('label.tree-toggler, label.tree1').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('ul.tree , ul.tree1').toggle(300);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li><label class="tree-toggler nav-header">WorkLoad</label>
    <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
      <li><label class="tree1">DME Report</label>
        <ul class="tree1">
          <li>
            <a href="search.php">Report1</a>
            <a href="search.php">Report2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="update.php">CAMB Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="index2.php">LMAB Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DMF Notification</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LME Forecast Report</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work in a generic way by attaching the click event handler only to `li` elements which have child `ul` using the `:has` selector. Then you can `toggle()` those `ul` within the click handler.

Also note the handler will need to call `stopPropagation()` on the event to stop the parent `li` from closing their child `ul` elements too. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('ul > li:has(ul)').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('> ul').toggle(300);
  });
});
```

```css
ul > li > ul {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li>
    <label class="nav-header">WorkLoad</label>
    <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
      <li>
        <label class="tree1">DME Report</label>
        <ul class="tree1">
          <li>
            <a href="search.php">Report1</a>
            <a href="search.php">Report2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="update.php">CAMB Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="index2.php">LMAB Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DMF Notification</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LME Forecast Report</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped